# Why my images aren't loaded from the web in .NET MAUI wen wrapped with a Frame element?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I have this code on the ViewModel with these properties:

```
    private string _fullName;
    public string FullName 
    { 
        get => _fullName;
        set
        {
            _fullName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FullName));
        } 
    }

    private string _imageUrl;
    public string ImageUrl 
    {
        get => _imageUrl;
        set
        {
            _imageUrl = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ImageUrl));
        }
    }
    // Some other properties
```

Then I have this code on the XAML:

```
        <Grid Margin="25">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Frame Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="100" HeightRequest="86" WidthRequest="86" HorizontalOptions="Center" Padding="0" IsClippedToBounds="True">
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Aspect="Fill"/>
            </Frame>
            <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="15">
                <Label Text="{Binding FullName}" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Email}" FontSize="Small" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
```

Every property is loaded, with the exception of the image. I was worried about this being some restriction with the Image control, however when I use just the Image control without being wrapped by a Frame element the image loads just fine.

```
        <!--This code works just fine-->
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Aspect="Fill"/>
```

Is there a limitation with the Frame control when it comes with handling images from the web? Both approaches work just fine when I load the image from the local Resources/Images folder. I also tried opening the image on the browser of the emulator and it works just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the code you provided and find this:

When it is:

```
<Frame Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="100" HeightRequest="86" WidthRequest="86" HorizontalOptions="Center" Padding="0" IsClippedToBounds="True">
      <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
             HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Aspect="Fill"/>
</Frame>
```

[The image will miss as you said that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FafXF.jpg).

However, if I remove `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions` of Image, the image will display well.

```
<Frame Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="100" HeightRequest="86" WidthRequest="86" HorizontalOptions="Center" Padding="0" IsClippedToBounds="True">
      <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
             Aspect="Fill"/>
</Frame>
```

And this is the [effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh3wu.jpg).

Comment: It's recommended to upload images instead of linking to imgur and other CDNs, because the links might get stale.

Comment: Thank you. I was able use that to fix it. It never really ocurred to me that Vertical and Horizontal options could have that effect.